# How to capture regex first occurence and interpolate into string with postgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to concatenate the digits from a string that starts with 'CityName' into a separate string. I have the concatenation part. My issue is being able to access the matches from the regex
I have a regex in rails that looks like `/CityName\s*(\d+)/i`. I'm super new to regex and it's hard for me to wrap my head around the docs. But I'm assuming that this regex will find any digits after the `CityName` case intensively. And then it's interpolated if it matches an attribute on my model.

```rb
regex = /CityName\s*(\d+)/i
if line_1 =~ regex
  "C#{$1}"
  ...
end
```

But further along in the execution, it's slowing down because I have to iterate over a lot of records. I have a query in psql that will do that calculations that I need, however I'm having a hard time implementing this regex replacement. My attempts so far look like:

```
CASE
    when addr.line_1 ~* 'CityName\s*(\d+)' then 'C' || regex_matches('CityName\s*(\d+)')[0]
...
```

I'm having a hard time finding a solution to grab the first occurrence of the regex match. Thanks for any tips :D

**EDIT:** I am trying to grab the digits after 'CityName' from a string if that string contains 'CityName'
Ultimately I need assistance with the regex and how to contactenate the digits with 'C'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Was able to finally start to figure out the regex. 
`WHEN addr.line_1 ~* '(?i)CityName\s*(\d+)' THEN 'C' || (SELECT (regexp_matches(addr.line_1, '(?i)CityName\s*(\d+)'))[1])`
The `(?i)` allowed for case insensitive matching for `CityName` and then the concatenation worked. Thank you @ti6on for pointing out the index difference with postgres :D

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. Are you trying to add the digits to your selection or to filter records based on them?

If you just want to select them:

```rb
Address.select(%q{(regexp_matches(addr.line_1, 'CityName\s*(\d+)'))[1] as digits})
  .map(&:digits)
```

If you want to filter based on then:

```rb
Address.where(%q{addr.line_1 ~ 'CityName\s*(\d+)'}).map &:email
  .map(&:line_1)
```

Also a few notes:

- Selecting digits case intensively does not really make sense. Digits
  does not have case.
- PostgreSQL arrays start from 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I was worried I wasn't explaining it well. I'm trying to add the digits that would result from the regex match to my selection. There are over 5k records, and because of that I am trying to do it using psql to help speed it up. I am able to make the query I need, but I need to group them by this regex match. Which is giving me a headache. For example I may have strings that may contain 'CityName 8' do grab the digits and concatenate them with the `'C' || ...`

Comment: I basically just need the digits from the regex. But having a hard time accessing the return from it

Comment: And I think the case insensitive part is for the CityName part of the string

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need a subquery or a WITH query:

`SELECT tbl1.col1, sum(...), min(...) FROM (SELECT ..., CASE ...yourregex stuff... END col1 FROM ...) tbl1 GROUP BY 1;`

`WITH tbl1 AS (SELECT ..., CASE ...yourregex stuff... END col1 FROM ...) SELECT t.col1, sum(...) FROM tbl1 t GROUP BY 1;`

If you need them regulary, you can also create views from the query or create a temp table, then you can use it in queries later.